# Why I am getting this output after this code ? Explain

Tags: r

I am currently started learning R language.and I am reading data.frames...and not able to understand an output I got...the code is-

```
newFactor<-factor(c("Pennsylvania","New York","New Jersey","New York",
                    "Tennessee","Massachusetts","Pennsylvania","New York"))
model.matrix(~newFactor-1)
```

[![this is the screenshot of the code along with the output I got on using R studio][1]][1]

Comment: Have you checked `?model.matrix`?  It is explained there.

Comment: Sorry Samar, I meant to show your image and somehow it got accidentally deleted, can you repost?